# How to switch between parent window and child window of IE using WIN32OLE

Tags: ruby, windows, automation, internet-explorer-11, win32ole

After struggling with selenium and finding out that it is impossible to use it in a system with sophisticated authorization, I decided to use WIN32OLE to automate my test cases.
But I have idea how to switch between parent window and child window of IE11
so here how a chunk of code looks like so far:

```
require 'win32ole'
@type = WIN32OLE_TYPE.new("Microsoft Internet Controls", "InternetExplorer")
@app = WIN32OLE.new("InternetExplorer.Application")
@app.visible = true
@app.navigate 'www.myaddress.com'
@app.document.getElementById('someID').click
```

Here a child window opens and I have to switch to it and work with that
and later switch back to parent window
Any ideas?
Thank you.